# pandas - accessing rows of a SparseDataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large SparseDataFrame (say, 20k indices x 10k columns) with a very low density (0.1% of the entries are set.) I'm trying to access to a specific **row** of the data frame, but I can't seem to be able to do so. Accessing columns is fine though. Here's a small example that illustrates the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5,3), index=list('abcde'))
df.loc['b',1] = np.nan  # for good measure...
sparse = df.to_sparse()

sparse[1]  # This is OK.
df.loc['b']  # This is also OK.
sparse.loc['b'] # This blows up.
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1020, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
  File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1145, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 68, in _get_label
    return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis, copy=True)
  File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2149, in xs
    new_values, copy = self._data.fast_2d_xs(loc, copy=copy)
  File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2714, in fast_2d_xs
    result[i] = blk._try_coerce_result(blk.iget((j, loc)))
  File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 275, in iget
    return self.values[i]
  File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/exp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/sparse/array.py", line 286, in __getitem__
    data_slice = self.values[key]
IndexError: too many indices
```

Note that on "normal", dense DataFrame objects it works well. However, due to the large dimensions I have it is a major inconvenience for me to either:

1. transpose the data frame (takes ages)
2. convert to a dense data frame (eats up way too much memory)

I'm relatively new to pandas, so maybe I'm missing something. In any case, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't use or know enough of the limitations of sparse dfs but this works: `sparse.loc['b':'b']` as does `sparse.ix['b':'b']`, still I don't why without using slicing it fails

Comment: @EdChum interesting observation. The difference I see is that slicing returns a DataFrame instead of a Series, so maybe the issue lies in this conversion somehow.

Comment: It's possible this is unimplemented: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pydata/YEdD8UrkV28, in fact it is already a request: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4400

Comment: what version of pandas? in 0.13 sparse changed a lot could be a bug/uninplemented, iirc

Comment: @Jeff: `pandas.__version__ == '0.13.0'`.

Comment: yep - then it's a bug/not implemented - pls file a report on github. if your frame is not too wide you can iterate over the columns and select each value to create a series (I'll have a look at the issue and let u know if I think of a way - haven't looked at sparse in a while)

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6076

Comment: Thanks @Jeff! I see the issue has been closed with a reference to the one you mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Jeff's comments on my question, it seems that indexing is not fully supported on Pandas' sparse data structures as of now. Hopefully this will change soon!

Related issues on GitHub:

- https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4400
- https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6076